# conditional count on mysql count

Tags: mysql, math, count, conditional-statements

I have two tables.
job_table.

```
job_id  job_type    job_type       *****
1       1           Day            *****
2       2           Night
3       3           Day & Night.
4       3           Day & Night.
```

and task_entry table.

```
task_entry_id    job_type       task_option_type
1                1             Day
2                1             Day
3                1             Day
4                2             Night
5                3             Day  
5                3             Night
6                3             Day  
7                3             Night
```

If job id is 3 then there will be 2 entries one for Day and one for Night.
Else only one entry.

I want to get the total count of jobs with task_entries like this,

```
job_id      task_entry_count
1           3
2           1
3           2
```

That is if job_type is 3 then count should be count/2. (Day&Night).
Else count should be normal count.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please post what you've tried to indicate some effort on your part.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the count of each job_type like this:

```
SELECT job_type, COUNT(*) AS task_entry_count
FROM task_entry
GROUP BY job_type;
```

As you said, this will double the count when job_type is 3. So, to account for that, you can just use a `CASE` statement to get one or the other:

```
SELECT job_type, CASE WHEN job_type = 3 THEN COUNT(*) / 2 ELSE COUNT(*) END AS task_count
FROM task_entry
GROUP BY job_type;
```

Keep in mind that here we are making the assumption there is 2 entries for each job_id = 3. If there's not, you will get back a value like 2.5, as seen in my [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9136b/1).